# How can I turn this "wheel" event for touch and/or drag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel, touch-event, gsap

Currently working on developing a Nuxt 3 application that includes a carousel feature which currently only works with horizontal scrolling. However, I have encountered a problem where only users with a trackpad are able to scroll.

To address this issue, I came up with the idea of implementing a "grab and scroll" event to allow users to scroll the carousel by clicking and dragging it left or right.

I have tried multiple solutions, but my current code is as follows:

```js
const carousel: any = ref();
const items: any = reactive([]);
const images: any = reactive([]);
const progressLine: any = ref();
const progress: any = ref(0);
const progressContent: any = ref(0);
const tweened = reactive({
    number: 0,
});
const duration = reactive({ number: 1 });

onMounted(async () => {
    await nextTick();

    let carouselWidth: any = carousel.value.clientWidth;
    let itemWidth: any = items[0].clientWidth;
    let itemPadding: any = 16 * (items.length - 1);
    let wrapWidth: any = items.length * itemWidth + itemPadding;
    let scrollPosition = 0;
    let maxScrollPosition: any;

    // Calculate the maximum scroll position
    maxScrollPosition = wrapWidth - carouselWidth;

    let handleScrollEvent = (e: { deltaX: any }) => {
        const { deltaX } = e;

        // Update the scroll position based on the mousewheel delta
        scrollPosition += deltaX;

        // Clamp the scroll position to prevent scrolling beyond the carousel edges
        scrollPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(scrollPosition, maxScrollPosition));

        // Calculate the progress of the scroll position as a percentage
        progress.value = (scrollPosition / maxScrollPosition) * 100;
        progressContent.value = progress.value;

        // Use GSAP to animate the carousel to the new scroll position
        gsap.to(carousel.value, { duration: duration.number, ease: 'expo.out', x: -scrollPosition });

        // Update the progress line width to match the scroll position
        gsap.to(progressLine.value, { duration: duration.number, ease: 'expo.out', width: `${progress.value}%` });
    };

    let handleTouchEvent = (e: {
        deltaX: any,
        touches: {
            clientX: any,
            0: { clientX: any },
        }[],
    }) => {
        const { touches } = e;

        // Get the touch position
        const touchPosition = touches[0].clientX;

        // Update the scroll position based on the touch delta
        scrollPosition += touchPosition;

        // Clamp the scroll position to prevent scrolling beyond the carousel edges
        scrollPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(scrollPosition, maxScrollPosition));

        // Calculate the progress of the scroll position as a percentage
        progress.value = (scrollPosition / maxScrollPosition) * 100;
        progressContent.value = progress.value;

        // Use GSAP to animate the carousel to the new scroll position
        gsap.to(carousel.value, { duration: duration.number, ease: 'expo.out', x: -scrollPosition });

        // Update the progress line width to match the scroll position
        gsap.to(progressLine.value, { duration: duration.number, ease: 'expo.out', width: `${progress.value}%` });
    };

    carousel.value.addEventListener('wheel', handleScrollEvent);
    carousel.value.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchEvent);

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        carouselWidth = carousel.value.clientWidth;
        itemWidth = items[0].clientWidth;
        itemPadding = 16 * items.length;
        wrapWidth = items.length * itemWidth + itemPadding;
    });
});
```

```html
<ul class="slider" ref="carousel">
    <li v-for="(project, i) in fetchedProjects" :key="project.slug" class="project-item" ref="items">
        <NuxtLink ref="project" v-if="project.img" class="project-link">
            <div class="project-figure">
                <img
                    :src="'https://picsum.photos/5' + i.toString().padStart(2, '0')"
                    :alt="project.description"
                    class="project-figure_img"
                    ref="images"
                />
                <span class="project-figure_span">{{ project.name }}</span>
            </div>
        </NuxtLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul.slider {
    --imgSize: 14.6875rem;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    li.project-item {
        flex: 0 0 var(--imgSize);
        &:not(:last-of-type) {
            margin-right: 1em;
        }
        div.project-figure {
            user-select: none;

            img {
                pointer-events: none;
                user-select: none;
                height: var(--imgSize);
                width: var(--imgSize);
                object-fit: cover;
            }
            span {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it is not working as intended. Every time I try to scroll the carousel, it resets to the starting position as if the scroll is relative to the window size rather than the carousel itself. This behavior is strange.

The "horizontal scrolling" event is working though.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracted your example into vanilla js as your issue looks unrelated to nuxt/vue. Here's a reduced example: https://codepen.io/team/hato/pen/QWVdMaK

Carousel logic seems working when you scroll/wheel on top of it as expected.

Hadn't tested on touch/mobile; was aiming to check if "resets to the starting position" occurred. I couldn't experience any glitch/resets so far. Only slowness is mainly down to the use of gsap to animate it, where the easing could create a sense of delay.

Added preventDefault to avoid window scrolling when user is interacting:

```
let handleScrollEvent = (e) => {
  
    e.preventDefault(); // added preventDefault to avoid window scrolling

    // rest of code ...

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to really fix the problem. It doesn't work as supposed.